# R - Numeric(int) to Date conversion

Tags: r, analysis, data-cleaning

I have a `date.frame` and a column with

```
values(20180213190133, 20180213190136, 20180213190173 , 20180213190193 , 20180213190213, 20180213190233, 20180213190333, 20180213190533, 20180213190733, 20180213190833, 20180213190833, 20180213190833, 201802131901833, 20180213191133, 20180213192133, 20180213194133, 20180213199133, 20180213199133, 20180213199133, 20180213199133, 20180213190136.... 1200 entries)
```

I want to convert this column which is of type `int` to `Date`.

I tried using :
`as.Date()` and `as.POSIXct()`. Both doesn't work. I am getting N/A value.

Please let me how can I convert this filed from int to Date.

Thanks

Comment: Because it's a integer. You have to convert it first to `character` and then to `Date`.

Comment: Thanks patL, I did convert it to character. But i still get NA.

`df <- as.Date.character(vp$ts , format = '%y%m%d%H%M')`

Comment: Try something like `as.POSIXct(values, origin = "1900-01-01")`, but with a different `origin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Input data

```
values<-c(20180213190133, 20180213190136, 20180213190173)

values_date<-as.Date(substr(as.character(values),start = 1,stop=8), format = "%Y%m%d")
> values_date
[1] "2018-02-13" "2018-02-13" "2018-02-13"
> class(values_date)
[1] "Date"
```

If you want to mantain also hour/minute/second you can try this:

```
values_date<-as.POSIXlt(as.character(values), format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

After this the class will be `"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"` and not `Date` but there are some strange info in your input data

In the third number, last two figures are "73", this number is incorrect for seconds and you will have `NA` in output.

```
values_date
[1] "2018-02-13 19:01:33 CET" "2018-02-13 19:01:36 CET" NA
```

Comment: Thanks Terru,

But i get date values as below,

`> values_date
[1] "1977-05-27" "1977-05-27" "1977-05-27"`

i want the output to be:

`[1] "2018-02-27" "2018-02-27" "2018-02-27"`

Comment: Answer changed according to this problem.

Comment: Hey Terru, It's working but partially. I do not get time. And when i put format as "%y%m%d%H%M%S", i get NA

Comment: Answer changed according to this point.

Comment: Hey, Thanks - it worked. Also,I added **'tz'** in my code and this works too.  
And yes, my input is incorrect, i just randomly typed some number.

 
`values1 <- as.POSIXct(values,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S", tz = "UTC")`

Comment: You are welcome!